# Facebook Graph API - Get the number of follower count of page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph, facebook-php-sdk

anyone can help me to get the followers count of facebook page? not fan count, all possible ways are welcome.

I read all old post, but without solution.

I tried to get by sum of all country, but total it's same at fan_count:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/id/insights/page_fans_country?access_token=token
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

try "https://graph.facebook.com/PAGEID/insights?metric=follower_count&period=day". For me it works..